# Logical Operator Python two == does not work in iteration dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, logical-operators

I have a dataframe and would like to select two rows to interpolate between these with a self defined function. The proplem is that I only see one row and dont understand why my of statement is not working. The data looks like the following:

```
        DataPoint   Rank
1       -9.360001   1.0
2       -9.080002   2.0
3       -9.039993   3.0
4       -7.529999   4.0
5       -7.479996   5.0
...     ...     ...     ...     ...
```

I would like to interpolate e.g. between rank 2.0 and 3.0. The code looks like the following:

```
Rank = data[['DataPoint']].count().values[0]*(1-0.99)
check_int = isinstance(Rank, int)
if not check_int:
        #loop 
        for ind in data.index:
            if (data['DataPoint'][ind] == (2.0 and 3.0)):
                print(data['DataPoint'][ind], data['Rank'][ind])
```

As Output I only receive:

> -9.03999300000001 3.0

but not in addition

> -9.080002     2.0

Comment: `data['DataPoint'][ind] == (2.0 and 3.0)` is equivalent to `data['DataPoint'][ind] == 3.0`. Because `2.0 and 3.0` is evaluated as `3.0`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, see if it works for you:
Basically the statement `(2.0 and 3.0)` picks only the lines with rank `3.0`
you need to specify a range manually like I did below:

```
ank = data[['DataPoint']].count().values[0]*(1-0.99)
check_int = isinstance(Rank, int)
if not check_int:
        #loop 
        for ind in data.index: # Below line, picks ranks more than 2.0 but less than 3.0
            if (data['Rank'][ind] >= 2.0 and data['Rank'][ind] <= 3.0):
                print(data['DataPoint'][ind], data['Rank'][ind])
```

Answer (score 2):

`(2.0 and 3.0)` evaluates to `3.0`, because that's the last thing to be evaluated. That's why you're missing `2.0`.

You could change this to an `in` to keep it on one line.

```
if data['Rank'][ind] in (2.0, 3.0):
    ...
```

Comment: According to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#when-to-use-trailing-commas), use `(2.0, 3.0)` instead of `(2.0, 3.0,)`

Comment: thanks this solution works too. But I like both approaches but only can selct one.